# How do I write an INI file to App Document Directory?

Tags: android, permissions, ini

I'm developing an order app, and after an order is correctly posted I would like to save some data locally for future use. To accomplish that I'm using an ini file stores in the App's Document folder, by using the writeGlobals() function define in the code below. I'm using path_provider and ini packages. My fileutil package is as follows:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:ini/ini.dart';

import '../global.dart';

Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localGlobalsFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/globals.ini');
}

Future readGlobals() async {
  final path = await _localGlobalsFile;
  // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
  if (File('$path').exists() == true) {
    _readGlobals();
  } else
    print(path.toString() + ' does not exist.');
}

_readGlobals() async {
  var file = await _localGlobalsFile;
  Config config = new Config.fromStrings(file.readAsLinesSync());
  glbShipCity = config.get("cart", "glbShipCity");
  glbShipHood = config.get("cart", "glbShipHood");
  glbPayType = config.get("cart", "glbPayType");
  glbName = config.get("cart", "glbName");
  glbPhone  = config.get("cart", "glbPhone");
  glbStreet = config.get("cart", "glbStreet");
  glbNumber = config.get("cart", "glbNumber");
  glbCompl = config.get("cart", "glbCompl");
  glbRef = config.get("cart", "glbRef");
  glbCEP = config.get("cart", "glbCEP");
  glbEmail = config.get("cart", "glbEmail");
  glbCPF = config.get("cart", "glbCPF");

  print("globals: ${config.get("cart", "glbShipCity")}");
  print("globals: ${config.toString()}");
}

Future writeGlobals() async {
  final file = await _localGlobalsFile;
  Config config = new Config();
  config.addSection("cart");
  config.set("cart", "glbShipCity", glbShipCity);
  config.set("cart", "glbShipHood", glbShipHood);
  config.set("cart", "glbPayType", glbPayType);
  config.set("cart", "glbName", glbName);
  config.set("cart", "glbPhone", glbPhone);
  config.set("cart", "glbStreet", glbStreet);
  config.set("cart", "glbNumber", glbNumber);
  config.set("cart", "glbCompl", glbCompl);
  config.set("cart", "glbRef", glbRef);
  config.set("cart", "glbCEP", glbCEP);
  config.set("cart", "glbEmail", glbEmail);
  config.set("cart", "glbCPF", glbCPF);
  print('Writing to ${file.path}');
  print("globals: ${config.toString()}");
  return file.writeAsString(config.toString());

}
```

All glb* variables are globally defined and work very well in every other parte of the app.
The structure of the ini file is correct, also.
Everything compiles and runs perfectly, except for the fact that nothing is written to the folder (which does not exist - or I at least can't see it - , by the way; I thought that it would be created when the app was installed...).

The function writeGlobals() does not throw any error, also, but the file is not written.
These problems occur both in the emulator and on an actual device.
So my questions are:

1. Do I need to explictly create the documente folder?
2. Does the app have to have some special permisson? In that case, how do I request it?

Thanks for tour help.

Comment: Please tell full path of that directory. Android Q?

Comment: The path returned by _localPath()  is 
 /data/user/0/br.inf.apoioinformatica.muitofacilemcasa/app_flutter.
The emuator's system image is R, API level 30, ABI x86, Android 10.0

Comment: That is your apps private folder. No other app has access. No file manager has access. No file explorer has access. You did not tell how you searched for the file and concluded that the file was not written.

Comment: I tried to find it 
1) Using the emulators file system app
2) Using the device's file system app
3) Using windows explorer , after connecting the phone via USB to the computer.
Interestingly enough, this folder shows in windows explorer:
Este Computador\Galaxy J8\Phone\data\user\0\com.samsung.android.allshare.service.fileshare

Comment: That is a different folder from the one you mentioned. Cannot your Android Studio or flutter ide show it? And is the file showing too?

Comment: I concluded that nothing was written (even if the folder is invisible and not accessible except by the app itself) because when I tried to read it back the app could not find it.

Comment: Actually, the problem is a little deeper, because it comes from my not understanding of tAndroid's file system. So if you could direct me to a simpler solution I'd appreciate. It does not have to be exactly this way. The only thing I need is a way to store and retrieve the information. The tutorials and docs made it look very easy, but I just can't make it work.

Comment: You did not answer my last comment.

Comment: My comment showing a folder that appears in \data\user was to say that that is the folder of some other app and it is accessible, but my app's folder is not there. I don't know how Android Studio can navigate to this folder, I'm new to it. Again, my doubt is: if the file is there (invisible or not) why can't I read it back? Must be doing something wrong then.

Comment: Android Studio has a Device File Explorer which can show your apps private directory. Indeed you should be able to read your file back if you used the same path.

Comment: Found it. But when I try to use it I get Android Debug Bridge not Found. I'll see how to fixx it.

Comment: Since the amount of data to be saved is very small I was able to do it by using SharedPreferences. I'd like to thank you for your attention and patience.